# Cannot include Boost headers in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, boost, header-files

I just built boost like this:

```
bjam toolset=msvc-11.0 variant=debug,release threading=multi link=static
```

I added include path: C:/boost/boost_1_50_0

Library path: C:/boost/boost_1_50_0/stage/lib

---

When I try to include Filesystem header

```
#include <boost\filesystem.hpp>
```

I get:  Error   1   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/filesystem.hpp': No such file or directory

However

```
#include <filesystem>
```

compiles just fine.

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: `#include <filesystem>` works because Visual C++ provides its own filesystem library (that is very similar to the Boost one, if not identical), so the header is being found in the system libraries folder.  Are you 100% sure that "C:/boost/boost_1_50_0/boost" is the top-level Boost headers folder?  Have you verified that the correct `-I` option is being passed to the compiler?

Comment: I had include path specified in "Include Directories". I added "C:/boost/boost_1_50_0" also to "Additional Include Directories" and now it works. Could you tell me why I have to specify include path here?